# How to remove border outline when clicking on styled link label?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following code for a styled link label:

```
extension Text {
    func styledLinkLabel<V: View & ShapeStyle>(with gradient: V) -> some View {
        self.fontWeight(.bold)
            .font(.title)
            .padding()
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 250, alignment: .center)
            .background(gradient)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding(2)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius:20)
                    .stroke(gradient, lineWidth:15)
            )
            .overlay(
                Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle.badge.plus")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .padding(.leading)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                , alignment: .leading)
            .padding(5)
    }
}
```

This is used in the code as follows:

```
 NavigationLink(destination: RentView(viewModel: RentViewModel(Amounts(), housemates: 1)))
                {
                    Text("1")
                        .styledLinkLabel(with: gradient)
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: RentView(viewModel: RentViewModel(Amounts(), housemates: 2)))
                {
                    Text("2")
                        .styledLinkLabel(with: gradient)
                }
```

However when I click on this in the app (screenshot below of a click in progress), the outline underneath shows. Is there any way to get rid of this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`compositingGroup`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/group/compositinggroup()):

```
extension Text {
    func styledLinkLabel<V: View & ShapeStyle>(with gradient: V) -> some View {
        self.fontWeight(.bold)
            .font(.title)
            .padding()
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 250, alignment: .center)
            .background(gradient)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding(2)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    .stroke(gradient, lineWidth: 15)
            )
            .overlay(
                Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle.badge.plus")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .padding(.leading)
                    .foregroundColor(.white),
                alignment: .leading
            )
            .compositingGroup() // <- add here
            .padding(5)
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, if you don't want to modify `styledLinkLabel`, you can use a custom `ButtonStyle`:

```
struct CustomButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .compositingGroup()
            .opacity(configuration.isPressed ? 0.5 : 1)
    }
}
```

```
NavigationLink(destination: Text("Destination")) {
    Text("Text")
        .styledLinkLabel(with: gradient)
}
.buttonStyle(CustomButtonStyle())
```